# How can I make this RESTful when it's requested with few parameters at once?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I made my routing just like this.  But what if genre was empty?
Isn't it going to redirect to example.com/shops/newest_first//california?
How can I solve this kind of routing and parameters problem??

**routes.rb**

```
match 'shops/:sort/:genre/:area', :to => 'shops#index'
```

**view**

```
<%= form_tag shops_path, :method => :get do %>
    <%= select_tag :sort, options_from_collection_for_select(Sort.all, 'id', 'name', params[:sort]), :prompt => "Newest first" %>
    <%= select_tag :genre, options_from_collection_for_select(Genre.all, 'id', 'name', params[:genre]), :prompt => "all" %>
    <%= select_tag :area, options_from_collection_for_select(Area.all, 'id', 'name', params[:area]), :prompt => "all" %>
<% end %>
```

**Another View**

Answer (score 1):

I would consider using GET params for things like area and sort since you are filtering indexes of other resources. You might also check the the section on [Dynamic Segments](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#dynamic-segments) in the guides, although that won’t help with the empty segment in the middle.